# what is Visual SourceSafe Explorer?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

May I know what visual sourcesafe explorer is and what it will do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual sourcesafe explorer is the (windows only) client program most often used to communicate with [visual sourcesafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) databases. It has an interface that sort of looks like the explorer in windows which I suppose lead to this name.
The program allows you to interact with the visual sourcesafe database. It is considered by many to be very user unfriendly, very limited in features, and generally a pain to use. If you are not forced by violence or exorbitant pay to use it I'd stay away from it, and any job that involves using it.

If you can make your own decisions, use [cvs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System), [subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software)), [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)), [mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial_(software)), [bazar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_(software)), or really anything suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400/source-control-system-for-single-developer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216834/source-control-system-for-small-database-dev-team), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360887/using-version-control-for-home-development) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141500/visual-studio-2008-source-control-for-small-teams).

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Sourcesafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302175.aspx) is an old source control system from Microsoft. It has not been updated in many years and is not suitable for use with new projects.

A better choice for source control might be [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org).

Comment: hi Mr.Greg Hewgill u r saying that visual sourcesafe is an old source control, but most of some developement companies are using this. how it is different from other i mean Subversion

Comment: If you're still using VSS for an old project, then the "Visual Sourcesafe Explorer" is the GUI interface to the VSS repository. Run it and view the Help menu within the application for more information.

Comment: Any company still using this is not a company you want to work for. Unless you are very hungry, and quite desperate to eat.